# Create observable from async class constructor

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

So we have an async class constructor like this

```
class Task {
    constructor(name, url) {
        return (async () => {
             this.name = name;
             this.response = await fetch(url);
             return this;             
        })();
    }
}
```

Then we want to use that in an observable chain like this

```
Observable.of({name: "Task1", url: "http://example.com"})
    .pipe(
        switchMap(item =>
            fromPromise(new Task(item.name, item.url)),
            (item, task) => ({item, task})
        )
    ).subscribe();
```

The constructor runs as expected. I have tried from, fromPromise and defer, to get the returned result of the constructor. Used tap to see if the async constructor ever emits. It does not.

Any help?

Comment: Did you realize about the type/quote error in `{name: "Task1, url: "http://example.com"}` ?

Comment: Yep, just fixed that. Thx

Comment: @Tom It looks like it works as should https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ixctur

Comment: @martin yes, thanks very much for setting up that sandbox. It's working with from. I'm slightly at a loss to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was Rx.js 5 vs 6.

There is no fromPromise in Rx.js 6.

This is the correct way, thanks for comments

```
Observable.of({name: "Task1", url: "http://example.com"})
    .pipe(
        switchMap(item =>
            from(new Task(item.name, item.url)),
            (item, task) => ({item, task})
        )
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: You can return a PromiseLike inside `switchMap`, no need to wrap it with `from`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vml7oy